# PHP array into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to assign a PHP array into a Javascript array, so I can use it into my chart.js file. I tried adding it into the javascript array but it didn't work, here is wat I have:
This is my PHP gathering form for my data to be stored into the array:

```
$id = $_SESSION['userId']; 
      $dBname = "infosensor";
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBname);

      $sql = "SELECT dias FROM `$id`;";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if ($resultCheck > 0)
      {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          // H:i:s -> Hora/minuto/segundo (H maior tem diferenca na forma de mostrar o horario, H maior -> 0h a 24h h menor -> 0h 12h)
          // d/m/Y -> dia/mes/ano
          $horario = (date('H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('.', '-', $row['dias']))));    

          $tempo[] = explode(',', $horario);

        }
      }
```

The result that I get from printing the array $tempo is:

```
Valor: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 16:29:47 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 16:30:07 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 16:33:55 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 16:34:25 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 16:34:41 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 16:59:26 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 16:59:36 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 17:02:38 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 17:05:55 ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 17:08:46 ) [10] => Array ( [0] => 17:08:47 ) [11] => Array ( [0] => 17:09:10 ) [12] => Array ( [0] => 17:45:25 ) [13] => Array ( [0] => 18:01:06 ) [14] => Array ( [0] => 18:05:55 ) [15] => Array ( [0] => 18:20:56 ) [16] => Array ( [0] => 19:26:19 ) [17] => Array ( [0] => 20:33:12 ) [18] => Array ( [0] => 20:33:17 ) [19] => Array ( [0] => 00:00:00 ) [20] => Array ( [0] => 09:17:48 ) [21] => Array ( [0] => 15:32:21 ) [22] => Array ( [0] => 15:40:18 ) [23] => Array ( [0] => 15:41:32 ) [24] => Array ( [0] => 23:51:15 ) [25] => Array ( [0] => 23:51:22 ) [26] => Array ( [0] => 23:56:30 ) [27] => Array ( [0] => 21:51:57 ) [28] => Array ( [0] => 21:52:18 ) [29] => Array ( [0] => 21:52:31 ) )
```

I need to store this datas like this:
Obs: This is just an example of how I need to store it.

```
var date = ["20:01:10", "10:23:20", "23:50:20", "07:23:20"];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to make it work? Additionally, be warned that your code is widely open to SQL injections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use JSON to pass the array to javascript.

```
var date = <?php echo json_encode($yourArray) ?>
```